# mysql large tables (>4Gb) corrupt after local server restart

Tags: mysql, crash

I hope someone can help me with this problem I'm having (I'm a newbie to Mysql and Stackoverflow, so it's probably something silly I'm missing)...

Whenever I build a large table in MySQL and then restart xampp's local MySQL server, the table then becomes unreadable under code runs that consider the 'whole' table - e.g. I can't drop it, run mySQLCheck on it or run any aggregation functions like `sum` / `count`.

This only happens after a server restart. It is fine when I build the table and then, without restarting, I run the 'whole table' codes on it I mentioned above.

Also, even after a server restart I can still do things like see the indexes in place, or sample the first x rows using `Limit`.

The error thrown is 'mysqld.exe has stopped working' - 'a problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available'

I stop and restart my server using the xampp start / stop control panel buttons

This only seems to happen when the table is more than 4gb. I'm using innodb

Thank you in advance!

Paul

===============================

An example of the error log result is below. This table (wikivisitstable10) was created by adding an index to the prior table. There are no crash issues with the prior table, just this one - and any similar tables >4gb:

```
`2016-08-25  0:22:57 6804 [Warning] option
'innodb-max-dirty-pages-pct': value 0 adjusted to 0.001 
2016-08-25 0:22:57 6804 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages 
2016-08-25  0:22:57 6804 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled  

2016-08-25  0:22:57 6804 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions 2016-08-25  0:22:57 6804
[Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used 2016-08-25  0:22:57 6804
[Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3 
2016-08-25  0:22:57 6804 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions   
2016-08-25 0:22:57 6804 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2016-08-25  0:22:57 6804 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of
buffer pool 
2016-08-25  0:22:57 6804 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported
file format is Barracuda. 
2016-08-25  0:22:57 6804 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 400931068139 and 400931068139 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 400931068159 in the ib_logfiles!
2016-08-25  0:22:57 6804 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown
normally! 
2016-08-25  0:22:57 6804 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash
recovery. 
2016-08-25  0:22:57 6804 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace
information from the .ibd files... 
2016-08-25  0:22:58 6804 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages  
2016-08-25 0:22:58 6804 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer... 
2016-08-25 00:22:59 1a94  InnoDB: Error: table 'revil2/page' 
InnoDB: in InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 180, InnoDB: but a tablespace with that id does not exist. There is InnoDB: a tablespace of name revil2/page and id 181, though. Have InnoDB: you deleted or moved .ibd files?   
InnoDB: Please refer to InnoDB: DATADICT LINK (REMOVED)
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue. 
2016-08-25  0:22:59 6804 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table revil2/wikipages7 in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 175, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary. 
InnoDB: Please refer to InnoDB: DATA DICT LINK (REMOVED) 
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue. 
2016-08-25 0:22:59 6804 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-08-25  0:22:59 6804 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-08-25  0:22:59 6804 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (PERCONA
WEBSITE (REMOVED)) 5.6.28-76.1 started; log sequence number
400931068159 
2016-08-25  0:22:59 5820 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started 
2016-08-25 00:22:59 16bc InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from .\\ib_buffer_pool 
2016-08-25  0:22:59 6804 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled. 
2016-08-25  0:22:59 6804 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'. 
2016-08-25 00:22:59 16bc InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 160825  0:22:59 
2016-08-25  0:23:00 6804 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '10.1.13-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution 
InnoDB: Error: trying to access page number 1794 in space 299, InnoDB: space name revil2/wikivisitstable10, InnoDB: which is outside the tablespace bounds.   
InnoDB: Byte offset 0, len 16384, i/o type 10. 
InnoDB: If you get this error at mysqld startup, please check that InnoDB: your my.cnf matches the ibdata files that you have in the InnoDB: MySQL server.   
2016-08-25 00:23:46 1388  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 5000 in file fil0fil.cc line 5866 
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap. InnoDB: Submit a detailed
bug report to HTTP BUGS. MYSQL. COM InnoDB: If you get repeated
assertion failures or crashes, even InnoDB: immediately after the
mysqld startup, there may be InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB
tablespace. 
Please refer to InnoDB: FORCING INNODB RECOVERY LINK (REMOVED) 
InnoDB: about forcing recovery. 160825  0:23:46 
[ERROR] mysqld got exception 0x80000003 ; This could be because you hit a
bug. It is also possible that this binary or one of the libraries it
was linked against is corrupt, improperly built, or misconfigured.
This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,  something
is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.1.13-MariaDB 
key_buffer_size=268435456
read_buffer_size=268435456 
max_used_connections=1 
max_threads=1001
thread_count=1 
It is possible that mysqld could use up to  key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 788380 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0x1c172e20 Attempting backtrace. You can use the
following information to find out where mysqld died. If you see no
messages after this, something went terribly wrong...
mysqld.exe!my_parameter_handler() mysqld.exe!my_mb_ctype_mb()
mysqld.exe!?get_ctx@MDL_ticket@@QBEPAVMDL_context@@XZ()
mysqld.exe!?get_ctx@MDL_ticket@@QBEPAVMDL_context@@XZ()
mysqld.exe!?functype@Item_func_dyncol_create@@UBE?AW4Functype@Item_func@@XZ()
mysqld.exe!?get_ctx@MDL_ticket@@QBEPAVMDL_context@@XZ()
mysqld.exe!?get_ctx@MDL_ticket@@QBEPAVMDL_context@@XZ()
mysqld.exe!?get_trg_event_map@Update_rows_log_event@@UAEEXZ()
mysqld.exe!?ha_check@handler@@QAEHPAVTHD@@PAUst_ha_check_opt@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!??_9handler@@$BBAE@AE()
mysqld.exe!?execute@Sql_cmd_check_table@@UAE_NPAVTHD@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?mysql_execute_command@@YAHPAVTHD@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?mysql_parse@@YAXPAVTHD@@PADIPAVParser_state@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?dispatch_command@@YA_NW4enum_server_command@@PAVTHD@@PADI@Z()
mysqld.exe!?do_command@@YA_NPAVTHD@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?threadpool_process_request@@YAHPAVTHD@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?tp_end@@YAXXZ() KERNEL32.DLL!SetUserGeoID()
ntdll.dll!TpSimpleTryPost() ntdll.dll!EtwNotificationRegister()
KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
ntdll.dll!RtlUnicodeStringToInteger()
ntdll.dll!RtlUnicodeStringToInteger()

Trying to get some variables. Some pointers may be invalid and cause
the dump to abort. Query (0x1c232750): CHECK TABLE
`wikivisitstable10` Connection ID (thread ID): 2 Status: NOT_KILLED`

 Optimizer switch:  index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,index_merge_sort_intersection=off,engine_condition_pushdown=off,index_condition_pushdown=on,derived_merge=on,derived_with_keys=on,firstmatch=on,loosescan=on,materialization=on,in_to_exists=on,semijoin=on,partial_match_rowid_merge=on,partial_match_table_scan=on,subquery_cache=on,mrr=off,mrr_cost_based=off,mrr_sort_keys=off,outer_join_with_cache=on,semijoin_with_cache=on,join_cache_incremental=on,join_cache_hashed=on,join_cache_bka=on,optimize_join_buffer_size=off,table_elimination=on,extended_keys=on,exists_to_in=on
```

Comment: Hi pn1618, were able to sort this out in the end? One of my InnoDB tables has recently hit 4GB and I get this same corruption issue.